# Firebase 3. authentication doesn't persist

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm working with firebase in a angularJS app, using the email and password authentication.
I just update my app from Firebase 2.x to 3.x and AngularFire from 1.x to 2.x.

I followed these 2 docs to do the migration :

- https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web
- https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md

But now, each time I refresh my page, I need to re-authenticate, like there is no persistent session.

I've checked the localStorage key `firebase:authUser` I have an `expirationTime` in the past (actually it's set with the timestamp of my login).

To check if the user is loggedin I use : `$firebaseAuth().$getAuth()`

**EDIT**

Here is a working example of my problem (login: *toto@mail.fr* / password: *toto123*)
https://plnkr.co/edit/463Hse?p=preview

Does anybody know why this behavior ?

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll be hard to help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I'm working on it (it's a very large app, so I need to simplify a lot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am gonna guess that you are checking the currentUser directly without waiting for the initial auth state to resolve. You need to add an observer:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Also, auth state is stored in web storage so make sure you have that enabled. (state will not persist in safari private mode browsing for example).

Comment: Alright, I'll try this. But it's a little confusing, when I was in Firebase 2.x and Angularfire 1.x I used `$firebaseAuth().$getAuth()` without waiting for the initial auth state to resolve. And in the migration guide of angularfire they said "Although all your promises and $getAuth() calls will continue to function, the auth payload will differ slightly". So I was thinking I had nothing to do.

Comment: Thanks it works, I know wait for `$waitForSignIn()` return his promise before checking if my user is auth and it seems to work.